# Non-owning entity side of @OneToOne/@ManyToOne/@ManyToMany

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, associations, persistence

I am trying to understand the javax.persistence annotations [@OneToOne](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html), [@ManyToOne](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ManyToOne.html) and [@ManyToMany](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ManyToMany.html).  The descriptions for these annotations make a mention of `non-owning side`.  Specifically:

> **[@OneToOne]:** *If the relationship is bidirectional, **the non-owning side** must use the mappedBy element of the OneToOne annotation to specify the relationship field or property of the owning side.*
>
> **[@ManyToOne]:** *If the relationship is bidirectional, **the non-owning** OneToMany entity **side** must used the mappedBy element to specify the relationship field or property of the entity that is the owner of the relationship.*
>
> **[@ManyToMany]:** *If the relationship is bidirectional, **the non-owning side** must use the mappedBy element of the ManyToMany annotation to specify the relationship field or property of the owning side.*

I am having trouble understanding this ownership aspect.  For example, I have the following associations:

[image: OneToOne]

[image: ManyToOne]

[image]

Note: Images taken from [here.](https://it.toolbox.com/blogs/craigborysowich/understanding-relationships-in-e-r-diagrams-020607)

---

> So which are the **non-owning entity sides** of these associations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the bi-directional relationship betweens two objects ,you have to choose which sides to manage the relationship. From the database perspective , managing the relationship means managing the value of some FK column that link between two tables. The side that managing it is called owning side. Otherwise, it is call non-owning side.

So back to your example on `ProjectManager` and `Project`. Which object is the owning side depends on which object you choose to manage their relationship.

If you choose `ProjectManager` to be the owning side (hence `Project` is the non-owning side), only the values of `ProjectManager#getProjects()` will be used to determine the value of such FK column. (i.e. `project` table 's `project_manager_id` column in this case) The value of `Project#getProjectManager()` will be ignored and does not affect the value of this FK column.

In term of JPA mapping , it is :

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="project_manager")
public class ProjectManager{

    @OneToMany
    private List<Project> projects = new ArrayList<>();

}

@Entity
@Table(name="project")
public class Project {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_manager_id")
    private ProjectManager projectManager;
}
```

On the other hands , if you choose `Project` to the owning side (hence `ProjectManager` is the non-owning side) , only the value of `Project#getProjectManager()` will be used to determine the value of this FK column while the value of `ProjectManager#getProjects()` will be ignored. The JPA mapping in the case will be :

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="project_manager")
public class ProjectManager{

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="projectManager")
    private List<Project> projects = new ArrayList<>();

}

@Entity
@Table(name="project")
public class Project {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_manager_id")
    private ProjectManager projectManager;
}
```

<sub>P.S: I explain it using [property access](https://thoughts-on-java.org/access-strategies-in-jpa-and-hibernate/) , hopefully you should get the idea.</sub>